# Mixed Interaction terms in linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, interaction

I am testing a mixed model with 4 predictors : 2 categorical predictors (with 6 and 7 levels respectively) and 2 quantitative predictors.

I would like to know if I am allowed, while testing my model, to create interaction terms in which I mix categorical and quantitative predictors.

Suppose `Y = f(a, b)` is the model I want to test, `a` is the quantitative predictor and `b` is the categorical predictor.

Am I allowed to search for (example in R):

```
linfit <- lm(Y ~ a +b +a:b, data=mydata)
```

The interpretation of the results is similar of the one I have when mixing quantitative predictors?

Comment: This is really a problem for Cross-Validated, as it has nothing to do with programming _per se_. Short answer: yes, that's perfectly acceptable. Interpretation is similar to any dummy-continuous interaction term.

Comment: Also, in `R`, the shorthand `a*b` encapsulates `a+b+a:b`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about Cross Validated. I will ask my statistical questions there from now on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you wrote is right, R will give you a result. And if the class of b is already been set up as factor, R will do the regression considering b as a categorical predictor.

Second, I assume you are asking about the statistical interpretation of the interaction term. The statistical meaning of the below three situations are not the same,
(1) a and b are quantitative predictors.
In the regression result from R, there will be four rows, a, b, a*b, interception. The regression process takes a*b as another quantitative variable and do linear regression.

`y = β0 + β1⋅a + β2⋅b + β3⋅a*b`

(2) a and b are categorical predictors. 
Suppose a has 3 levels and b has 2. Draw out the the design matrix which is consisted with 1 or 0;

`y = β0 + β1⋅a2 + β2⋅a3 + β3⋅b2 + β4⋅a2*b2 + β5⋅a3*b2`

(3) a is categorical and b is quantitative predictor.
Suppose a has 3 levels.

`y = β0 + β1⋅a2 + β2⋅a3 + β3⋅b + β4⋅a2*b + β5⋅a3*b`

For more details of interaction term and design matrix, generalized linear model will talk more about it. Also, it's easy to try it out in R from the regression results.

Comment: It is in general unwise advice to suggest separate interpretation of interaction coefficients.  It's also really an off-topic SO question so I joined MichaelChirico in voting to migrate it.